# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "published" is of type bit but expression is of type bytea

Tags: spring, database, postgresql, spring-boot

When trying to store bit instead of boolean in postgres using spring boot, it is throwing error.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "published" is of type bit but expression is of type bytea
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Tried the below two ways:

1. @Column(name = "published", columnDefinition = "bit default '0")
   private boolean published;
2. @Column(name = "published", columnDefinition = "BIT default '0'")
   private byte[] published = {'0'};

Issue is causing only with postgres.
With MySQL and oracleDb it is working fine.

Comment: Pretty sure the error is coming from `private byte[]` as I am guessing that is being cast to an array of `bytea` types. 1) Postgres has a proper [boolean](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) so you should use that, instead of coercing `bit`. 2) If you want to use [bit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html) read the docs at the lonk.

Comment: Yeah, that is right. In MySQL bit(1) is one bit, but in postgres it is 1byte. Will use boolean instead of bit(1). Thanks @Adrian